# How can I use useEffect in React correctly when creating simple counter logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am working on some simple logic that I am having trouble with.
I want to create a very basic counter that increments when a button is pressed, but I am not getting the expected result.

Here is my original logic:

```
 const Counter = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.getElementById("count").addEventListener("click", countClick);
    });

    const countClick = () => {
        document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button id="count">
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

This approach does not work and after I click a certain amount of times the browser freezes. Also, the count in the title tab is not in sync with what's being displayed in my paragraph. For example, if I click the button twice the tab title would say that I clicked once.

What would be the best approach to get the expected results?
I was thinking I could move the countClick function to a useCallback() hook like this:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("count").addEventListener("click", countClick);
  }, [countClick]);



  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button id="count">Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When doing this, it doesn't freeze any more, but the count in the title tab is remaining at 0 and also I am getting the warning to add count to the dependency array for useCallback(), but when adding it, it throws my count all the way off.

Comment: You should take a look at the [React documentation for adding interactivity](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/adding-interactivity). At the moment you're introducing vanilla JS DOM methods which will conflict with the way that React works.

Comment: When you use `getElementById` or `addEventListener` it usually means you are doing something wrong

Comment: The most important problem here - which causes the browser to freeze - is that you add a new handler function for the click event *on every single render*, and never remove any of these. You should read more into the docs of useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be useEffect? For something like a count useReducer might be the way to go. [Here is a simple useReducer counter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6uucdp?file=src/App.js). Or you could just increase the useState count by 1 whenever the button was pressed.

```
const countReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };

    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(countReducer, { count: 0 });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Count:{state.count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const countClick = useCallback(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
    setCount((prevCount) => (prevCount + 1));
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => countClick()}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey this doesn't update the title tab also.

Comment: added `count` as dependency to useCallback

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best approach**

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// Importing app.css is css file to add styling
import "./App.css";
  
const App = () => {
  //  Counter is a state initialized to 0
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  
  // Function is called everytime increment button is clicked
  const handleClick1 = () => {
    // Counter state is incremented
    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }
  
  // Function is called everytime decrement button is clicked
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    // Counter state is decremented
    setCounter(counter - 1)
  }
  
  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      fontSize: '300%',
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      top: '-15%',
    }}>
      Counter App
      <div style={{
        fontSize: '120%',
        position: 'relative',
        top: '10vh',
      }}>
        {counter}
      </div>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button style={{
          fontSize: '60%',
          position: 'relative',
          top: '20vh',
          marginRight: '5px',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          borderRadius: '8%',
          color: 'white',
        }}
          onClick={handleClick1}>Increment</button>
        <button style={{
          fontSize: '60%',
          position: 'relative',
          top: '20vh',
          marginLeft: '5px',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          borderRadius: '8%',
          color: 'white',
        }}
          onClick={handleClick2}>Decrement</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
  
export default App
```

[image]